# Is an array of 2D arrays a 3D array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, definition

I'm struggling with the concept of defining a 3D array. I see 1 dimension as a single array, 2 dimensions as a 'grid', and 3 dimensions as a 'cube'. What therefore is an array of 2D arrays counted as?
[image]

Comment: Unless you're asking this in a context of some library of programming environment - that is a matter of interpretation. Isn't the cube an "array" of 2D slices, each of which is a 2D array? If your answer is "no", then - why not?

Comment: I'm currently planning a report, thus it is not in the context of a programming environment - more a thought experiment. I think I see the logic now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a programming language is an easy way to make a model of some data. But it is obviously more difficult to imagine the realisation of a model.

Consider the following:

- A one-dimensional array is a list of pointers to data-values. Pointers and values are pairs. The data-value can be simple forms like byte, integer, char or boolean. However they are called in your programming language. Or it can be a pointer to more complex data like strings, structs, unions, .. It can be a pointer to other arrays at well.

> What therefore is an array of 2D arrays

In your example a one-dimensional array of 2D-arrays could be a collection of two-dimensional pointers (e.g. screen-coordinates).

Most of the languages do not call it pointers because it is difficult to understand and prefer the idea of 1,2,3 or even more dimensional boxes with a certain content. But nevertheless you call it - the idea is maybe clearer now to you.

Comment: Your conclusion slightly confuses me, are you saying that an array with pointers to values of a 2D array is simply another word for a 3D array or that a 3D array is something different?

Comment: A 3D-Array is different. You can visualize it as a cube and every coor in this cube is a pointer to a data-value.

Answer (score 1):

Think of an unidimensional array as a line, a 2D array as a dollar bill and a 3D array (which is the same as an array of 2D arrays) as a wad of bills.

Comment: This is a good analogy for 2D and 3D arrays, thank you.